# Intel RAID within the motherboard persistence information

Tags: raid, intel-rst

I was wondering: where the Intel RAID (fakeraid) controller available on many mainstream motherboard persist the raid information? On the disks or in some solid memory on the motherboard?

**EDIT**

BTW I removed the `dmraid` metadata with the linux command:

```
sudo dmraid -rE
```